# How can I decrypt this m3u8 and key file to mp4, Maybe its use javascript to decryptdata

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, m3u8

**THIS** is the video website:
[the video website link](https://www.sciconf.cn/m/lives/details/2601?video_id=151629&lang=cn)

From this video link, I download the m3u8, key.key and ts video files, and use **FFMPEG** to transform these files to mp4.
but **Error:**

```
ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i a.m3u8 -c copy 01.mp4
ffmpeg version N-94813-g85386c36e3-ffmpeg-for-N_m3u8DL-CLI Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.0 (GCC)
  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
  libavcodec     58. 56.101 / 58. 56.101
  libavformat    58. 32.104 / 58. 32.104
  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
[hls @ 007e3000] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 007e3000] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES')
[hls @ 007e3000] Opening 'a.key' for reading
[hls @ 007e3000] Opening 'crypto:43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2_0.ts' for reading
[hls @ 007e3000] Opening 'crypto:43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2_1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 007e3000] Error when loading first segment '43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2_0.ts'
a.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The key file is

```
00000000h: 46 F5 50 A3 7A 46 85 B5 8C 17 5B 0E 4B 8D F5 49 ; F鮌F叺?[.K嶕I
00000010h: F1 02 79 41 58 C7 A3 D3 17 90 0D D6 27 67 D6 D0 ; ?yAX牵???g中
```

and the IV value in the m3u8 file is

```
IV=0x786d9270e353d8758b621c1f775491f2
```

Too long bytes to FFMPEG.

---

In my limited experience with html and javascript, I found the Chrome blob a random named javascript file when the website page freshed.

Chrome - Network log:

```
XHR:43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2.m3u8?pid=1608691204584X1511260&device=desktop
XHR:43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2.key?token=1df110e5-ff1d-42de-bd39-b63304bb3062-53648385
XHR:43924590506ad94e644d0bfac89e14b9_2_0.ts?pid=1608691204584X1511260&device=desktop
Other:blob:https://www.sciconf.cn/93ebcbe3-0211-4ec0-94df-421024e8b505
```

Some codes in the javascript file (`blob:https://www.sciconf.cn/93ebcbe3-0211-4ec0-94df-421024e8b505`)like:

```
o = function() {
                function t(t, e, i, n) {
                    this.decryptdata = i,
                    this.discardEPB = n,
                    this.decrypter = new v.a(t,e,{
                        removePKCS7Padding: !1
                    })
                }
                var e = t.prototype;
                return e.decryptBuffer = function(t, e) {
                    this.decrypter.decrypt(t, this.decryptdata.key.buffer, this.decryptdata.iv.buffer, e)
                }
```

I think the website use this js file to decrypt the key file and the IV value, but I can't add breakpoint to the random named js file.

---

**I am studying this for a long time, but no use.**

**Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve the decrypted key and IV?**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, code or logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct `Chrome - Network log`?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It's blob a random named javascript file (blob:https://www.sciconf.cn/93ebcbe3-0211-4ec0-94df-421024e8b505)